# PHP update show's success message regardless of execution

Tags: php, mysql, sql-update

I have a SQL statement that's supposed to UPDATE a record in my DB.

The statement works, but it displays the success message before the button has been hit. So that means the success message is always displayed.

Also, if you click on a record to update it and you decide you don't want to update anything and click the cancel button or on another link to go off the page, it updates the record with blank inputs.

Here's my code:

```
try {

    $conn = new PDO('mysql:host=' . Config::get('mysql/host') . ';dbname=' . Config::get('mysql/db'), Config::get('mysql/username'), Config::get('mysql/password'));
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    $job_id = $_GET['job_id'];

    $jobs = DB::getInstance()->query("SELECT * FROM jobs WHERE job_id=$job_id");

    $job_title = isset($_POST['job_title']) ? $_POST['job_title'] : '';
    $date = isset($_POST['date']) ? $_POST['date'] : '';
    $location = isset($_POST['location']) ? $_POST['location'] : '';
    $type = isset($_POST['type']) ? $_POST['type'] : '';
    $description = isset($_POST['description']) ? $_POST['description'] : '';
    $education = isset($_POST['education']) ? $_POST['education'] : '';
    $experience = isset($_POST['experience']) ? $_POST['experience'] : '';
    $competencies = isset($_POST['competencies']) ? $_POST['competencies'] : '';
    $how_apply = isset($_POST['how_apply']) ? $_POST['how_apply'] : '';

    $sql = "UPDATE jobs SET job_title='$job_title', date='$date', location='$location', type='$type', description='$description', education='$education', experience='$experience', competencies='$competencies', how_apply='$how_apply' WHERE job_id=$job_id";
    $result = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $result->execute();

    echo $result->rowCount() . ' record updated successfully';
    Redirect::to('manage_jobs.php');

} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo $sql . '<br />' . $e->getMessage();
}
```

Also, if the query is supposedly successful, it's supposed to redirect you back to the list if records, but, as soon as you open the record and click the UPDATE link, it redirects back, but it replaces the current data with blank value, not even giving me the opportunity to update anything. It doesn't open the update form.

Comment: `Redirect` == `header('Location: ')` ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should wrap your code in to an if

```
if (isset($_POST['job_title'])) {
    //Your entire code that you posted
}
```

And you should pre-compilate all the inputs, because otherwise, it will fill you with empty inputs.